# Error in Partitioning SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

SQL Server 2008 EE with a compatibiliry level 2005.
One of my partitions (Runnig on the analysis services) is raising the following error:

```
Message
Executed as user: xxxxxxxx\servicesadmin. <return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis"><results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/xmla-multipleresults"><root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty"><Exception xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception" /><Messages xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception"><Error ErrorCode="3238002695" Description="Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" /><Error ErrorCode="3238002695" Description="Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" /><Error ErrorCode="3238395904" Description="OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Query timeout expired; HYT00." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" /><Error ErrorCode="3240034318" Description="Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the 'Fact_2014' partition of the 'General Ledger' measure group for the 'FINANCE_Analysis' cube from the FINANCE_Analysis database." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" /><Error ErrorCode="3239837702" Description="Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" /></Messages></root></results></return>.  The step failed.
```

I ran the same query (not through the partition)  at the Database Engine  and the query finished successfully 3 hours later, but when I ran it from the partition (on Analysis services), I am getting the above error message.

What is wrong?

I am thinking to extend the timeout, but I wanted your opinion first, before i perform changes.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: You should include the pertinent part(s) of the error message so that people don't have to dig through all that XML.  From what I gather `Query timeout expired` does indeed mean that increasing the command timeout would probably allow this to complete.  Have you tried that?

Comment: The timeout have value zero, which it's unlimited... maybe i looked a wrong timeout property! I really don't understand.